# how to map this following api response in react js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image]

hello i want to map this but somehow i am not able to do that , in current code its saying me that it is a function..

id.js

```
function detail({ ninja }) {
const [data, setdata] = useState([ninja]);
console.log(data);
return (
    <div>
        <>
            {data.map((inner) => (
                <>
                    {inner.data.map((books) => (
                        <>
                            <div>
                                <h1 id='home_heading'>{books.name}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    ))}
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    </div>
);
```

}

export default detail;

please provide me a solution to this problem or an alternative method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `map` is redundant.

```js
<>
    {data.map((book) => (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1 id='home_heading'>{book.data.name}</h1>
            </div>
        </>
    ))}
</>
```

`map` works on arrays. `inner.data` is an object and so will error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and remember to add a key while using map, for more information check https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-the-map()-function-to-export-javascript-in-react

and also the official documentation - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#embedding-map-in-jsx

```js
function detail({ ninja }) {
const [data, setdata] = useState([ninja]);
console.log(data);
return (
    <div>
         {data.map((item) => (
             <div key={<add the unique key value here>}>
                   <h1 id='home_heading'>{item?.data?.name}</h1>
             </div> 
          ))}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, used `dataset` variable to make runnable code. you may use the useState hook in your code instead of `dataset` variable.

```
export default function App() {
  var dataset=[{"id":2,"name":"book1"},{"id":2,"name":"book2"}]
  return (
    <div>
        <>
            {dataset.map((books) => (
                <>
                    <div>
                        <h1 id='home_heading'>{books.name}</h1>
                    </div>
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    </div>)
}
```

Output:[image]